# How can I return a vector with a dataframe inside in R?

Tags: r

Here is a challenge for you: I was trying to make a tic tac toe based on R. First, the players have to configure putting in the name of the players, and the game should check if the name exists in a file called "Players.txt" (if not, the game will create one), if the name exists, the game will ask for a new one. The last part of the game is that the game should record all the punctuation of the players (each gambling chip used will subtract 5 points of 100 that the player has at the beginning of the game). The problem is when a player wins, the game shows the following error: "Error in table[location_name1, 3]: Incorrect number of dimension in R".

Comment: Some comments if I may: the code has many redundancies and many variable or function names do not explain the purpose of these objects. You could make your code a lot easier to maintain by improving your coding skills.
I also recommend that you make yourself familiar with breakpoints and other debugging features in Rstudio that will help you to track down such errors yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A vector can either be atomic or a list. Atomic vectors can only contain elements of one and the same data type. That means, you are "accidentally" creating a list with

```
vector=c(win,name1,name2,table)
```

with the result that each column of the data frame should become an entry.

You can solve it with

```
vector <- list(win, name1, name2, table)
```

`vector` is still a list but now it has the format I believe you want.

Having done that you still get errors. The reason is that these assignments fail.

```
location_name1=which(grepl(name1,table$gamers))
location_name2=which(grepl(name2,table$gamers))
```

They return an empty vector because earlier in the code you set `win=vector[1]`... `table=vector[4]`. Since `vector` is now a list, you have to subset it accordingly. That means you have to chance the statements to `table=vector[[4]]`.

Now you are going to get another problem. The reason is that you treat the columns `table$scores` as text. When you read the data you need to make sure that this columns is not interpreted as text. You also have to eliminate all statements that coerce the column into text. Otherwise `table[location_name1,3]=table[location_name1,3]+pointsx` will obviously fail because you cannot add a number to a string.

For example, you coerce the column into a character column with this statement:

```
name1 <- data.frame(gamers=name1,games="1",scores="100")
```

`games` and `scores` are strings not numbers. Another example is the assigment after reading the table from the file. You can make sure that `scores`are numeric by doing this.

```
scores <- as.numeric(table[,3])
```

Please get familiar with Rstudio debugging capabilities (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio). This way you can go through your code line by line and check consequences of each assignment to the data frame.

Comment: What is Descr in the list?

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error. If removed it. It had no meaning for you.

Comment: I don't know why but it still doesn´t work. Do you want to see the entire code?

Comment: I certainly need more. E.g. there are some things in function `a` that I do not understand. You make the equivalent assigment several times. Long story short: please update your question with more details.

Comment: What should I do to make sure that table$scores are not interpreted as text?